# C# HttpClient PostAsync request is returning a Bad Request status

Tags: c#, httpclient, postasync

When running the below C# HttpClient PostAsync request I am getting a bad request status. I'm not sure why this is. I have a username and password that I am passing. Not sure whether I am adding that correctly. New to this.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var data = "{'Locations' : '[50.452603, 30.522025]'}";
    var endpoint = new Uri("https://api.connect.test.com/risk/v3/countr/pop/location?");
    var newPostJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    var payload = new StringContent(newPostJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
    var status = client.PostAsync(endpoint, payload).Result.StatusCode.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(status);
}
```

Comment: what does this `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);` output? does it become a json the server expects? afaik, it turns into string literal, not json.

Comment: Try `var payload = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

Comment: @Clemens thank you. I am still getting a bad request when I make the suggested amendment.

Comment: Your URI has a question mark at the end.  The question mark indicates there should be parameters that follow.  You have no parameters.

Comment: @jdweng so I need to add the post data there and not in the content? What's the best way to do that?

Comment: You do not need the question mark if you do not have parameters.  Parameter can be either in the URI, HTTP Headers, or in the Body.  In your case the parameters are json in the body.

Comment: @jdweng ok thank you. That makes sense. I am still getting a bad request response, when I remove the question mark. And it can't be that it has to be in the URI?

Comment: Bad request means the format (or contents) of the request does not meet the server requirements.  It probably means you do not have valid json like Bagus Tesa says.  But it could be a lot of other reasons.  Check the server documentation.  Every server is different.

Comment: The documentation says it returns values for a list of locations. When I amended the request to var data = "{\"Locations\" : [[50.452603, 30.522025], [50.401813, 30.521898]]}"; and applied @BagusTesa answer below I got an OK response. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `data` is not a valid json.

```
var data = "{'Locations' : '[50.452603, 30.522025]'}";
```

It should be

```
var data = "{\"Locations\" : [50.452603, 30.522025]}";
```

This way, you can pass it directly to `StringContent`.

```
var payload = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

If you really want to use that `JsonConvert.Serialize`, you can make a POCO to store the data.

```
public class Location
{
    public List<double> Locations = new List<double>();
}
```